# mpandroid chart certain methods unable to resolve

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

So I'm using the awesome MPAndroid Chart library to make a simple LineChart. I was able to customize it heavily using the example project on GitHub.

The problem is, when I move it to my own code, certain methods are no longer able to be resolved:

mLineChart.setExtraOffsets() and mLineChart.setAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled() in particular. There might be others but these are the only two I've noticed.

Everything else works fine though. Any idea why I can't access these two methods? What should I dig into to find out more about why this is the case?

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
private LineChart mLineChart;

// stuff here

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // stuff here

    // Creating numbers line chart for candidate
    LineChart numChart = (LineChart)view.findViewById(R.id.numbersLineChart);
    setNumChart(numChart, mObject.getNums());

    // stuff here
    }

public void setNumChart(LineChart lineChart, List<Integer> nums){

    mLineChart = lineChart;
    mLineChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

    // no description text
    mLineChart.setDescription("");
    mLineChart.setNoDataTextDescription("You need to provide data for the chart.");

    // enable value highlighting
    mLineChart.setHighlightEnabled(true);

    // enable touch gestures
    mLineChart.setTouchEnabled(true);

    // enable scaling and dragging
    mLineChart.setDragEnabled(false);
    mLineChart.setScaleEnabled(false);

    // if disabled, scaling can be done on x- and y-axis separately
    mLineChart.setPinchZoom(false);

    // create a custom MarkerView (extend MarkerView and specify the layout to use for it)
    MyMarkerViewv2 mv = new MyMarkerViewv2(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_marker_view, mLineChart);

    // set the marker to the chart
    mLineChart.setMarkerView(mv);

    // disable all axes lines and labels
    YAxis leftAxis = mLineChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setEnabled(false);

    mLineChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

    XAxis bottomAxis = mLineChart.getXAxis();
    bottomAxis.setEnabled(false);

    // add data
    setLineChartData(nums);

    //THIS METHOD CANNOT BE RESOLVED********************
    mLineChart.setExtraOffsets(30f,50f,30f,0f);

    // get the legend (only possible after setting data)
    Legend l = mLineChart.getLegend();
    l.setEnabled(false);

    mLineChart.invalidate();

}

public void setLineChartData(List<Integer> nums){

    //create xVariables aka strings of the months
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        xVals.add(Month.getMonthfromIndex(i).getAbbrev());
    }

    //add corresponding numbers
    ArrayList<Entry> yVals = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        yVals.add(new Entry(nums.get(i), i));
    }

    // create a dataset and give it a type
    LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals, "DataSet");

    set1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    set1.setCircleColor(Color.BLACK);
    set1.setLineWidth(0.75f);
    set1.setDrawCircles(true);
    set1.setDrawValues(false);
    set1.setCircleSize(1.75f);
    set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);

    ArrayList<LineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<LineDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(set1); // add the datasets

    // create a data object with the datasets
    LineData data = new LineData(xVals, dataSets);

    // set data
    mLineChart.setData(data);
}

// stuff here

class MyMarkerViewv2 extends MarkerView {

    private TextView markerContent;
    private LineChart mChart;

    public MyMarkerViewv2(Context context, int layoutResource, LineChart lChart) {
        super(context, layoutResource);

        mChart = lChart;
        markerContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.markerContent);
    }

    // callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
    // content (user-interface)
    @Override
    public void refreshContent(Entry e, int dataSetIndex) {

        if (e instanceof CandleEntry) {
            CandleEntry ce = (CandleEntry) e;

            List<String> months = mChart.getLineData().getXVals();
            markerContent.setText(months.get(e.getXIndex() % 12) + "\n" + Utils.formatNumber(ce.getHigh(), 0, true) + "%");
        } else {
            List<String> months = mChart.getLineData().getXVals();
            markerContent.setText(months.get(e.getXIndex() % 12) + "\n" + Utils.formatNumber(e.getVal(), 0, true) + "%");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getXOffset() {
        // this will center the marker-view horizontally
        return -(getWidth() / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public int getYOffset() {
        // this will cause the marker-view to be above the selected value
        return -getHeight();
    }
}
```

I also have the LineChart wrapped inside a vertical LinearLayout with other elements and that whole thing wrapped inside a ScrollView. Not sure if that's what's causing the problem or not.

Comment: Please include all of the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. It's because the library downloaded by Maven and Gradle is not exactly the same as the one included in the example project on the website.